# How do I determine which telerik RadListBoxItem is being dragged from the RadListBox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, telerik, radlistbox

I have a telerik `radlistbox` with several list items within. They each have their own text and are draggable. I make use of the radlistbox `OnClientDropped` method and want to obtain the text of the `radlistboxitem` that was dropped.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it.  I decided to approach it a little differently after thinking about it, but the same basic solution applies.  You can obtain the source item (what you're dragging/dropping) through the event args in a clientside method.  At that point all you need to do is grab the pertinent information (in my case, the text of the item being dragged/dropped).

The javascript involved:

```
function OnClientDragStartHandler(sender, e) {    
    var objType = e.get_sourceItem().get_text();
}
```

Thanks